# Can neural networks handle redundant inputs?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, neural-network, training-data, loss-function

I have a fully connected neural network with the following number of neurons in each layer `[4, 20, 20, 20, ..., 1]`. I am using TensorFlow and the 4 real-valued inputs correspond to a particular point in space and time, i.e. (x, y, z, t), and the 1 real-valued output corresponds to the temperature at that point. The loss function is just the mean square error between my predicted temperature and the actual temperature at that point in (x, y, z, t). I have a set of training data points with the following structure for their inputs:

---

### (x,y,z,t):

(0.11,0.12,1.00,0.41)

(0.34,0.43,1.00,0.92)

(0.01,0.25,1.00,0.65)

...

(0.71,0.32,1.00,0.49)

(0.31,0.22,1.00,0.01)

(0.21,0.13,1.00,0.71)

---

Namely, what you will notice is that the training data all have the same redundant value in `z`, but `x`, `y`, and `t` are generally not redundant. Yet what I find is my neural network cannot train on this data due to the redundancy. In particular, every time I start training the neural network, it appears to fail and the loss function becomes `nan`. But, if I change the structure of the neural network such that the number of neurons in each layer is `[3, 20, 20, 20, ..., 1]`, i.e. now data points only correspond to an input of (x, y, t), everything works perfectly and training is all right. But is there any way to overcome this problem? (Note: it occurs whether any of the variables are identical, e.g. either `x`, `y`, or `t` could be redundant and cause this error.) I have also attempted different activation functions (e.g. ReLU) and varying the number of layers and neurons in the network, but these changes do not resolve the problem.

My question: is there any way to still train the neural network while keeping the redundant `z` as an input? It just so happens the particular training data set I am considering at the moment has all `z` redundant, but in general, I will have data coming from different `z` in the future. Therefore, a way to ensure the neural network can robustly handle inputs at the present moment is sought.

A minimal working example is encoded below. When running this example, the loss output is `nan`, but if you simply uncomment the `x_z` in line 12 to ensure there is now variation in `x_z`, then there is no longer any problem. But this is not a solution since the goal is to use the original `x_z` with all constant values.

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf

end_it = 10000 #number of iterations
frac_train = 1.0 #randomly sampled fraction of data to create training set
frac_sample_train = 0.1 #randomly sampled fraction of data from training set to train in batches
layers = [4, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 1]
len_data = 10000
x_x = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.,len_data)])
x_y = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.,len_data)])
x_z = np.array([np.ones(len_data)*1.0])
#x_z = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.,len_data)])
x_t = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.,len_data)])
y_true = np.array([np.linspace(-1.,1.,len_data)])

N_train = int(frac_train*len_data)
idx = np.random.choice(len_data, N_train, replace=False)

x_train = x_x.T[idx,:]
y_train = x_y.T[idx,:]
z_train = x_z.T[idx,:]
t_train = x_t.T[idx,:]
v1_train = y_true.T[idx,:] 

sample_batch_size = int(frac_sample_train*N_train)

np.random.seed(1234)
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

class NeuralNet:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, t, v1, layers):
        X = np.concatenate([x, y, z, t], 1)  
        self.lb = X.min(0)
        self.ub = X.max(0)
        self.X = X
        self.x = X[:,0:1]
        self.y = X[:,1:2]
        self.z = X[:,2:3]
        self.t = X[:,3:4]
        self.v1 = v1 
        self.layers = layers 
        self.weights, self.biases = self.initialize_NN(layers) 
        self.sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=False,
                                                     log_device_placement=False)) 
        self.x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x.shape[1]])
        self.y_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.y.shape[1]])
        self.z_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.z.shape[1]])
        self.t_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.t.shape[1]])
        self.v1_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.v1.shape[1]])  
        self.v1_pred = self.net(self.x_tf, self.y_tf, self.z_tf, self.t_tf) 
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v1_tf - self.v1_pred)) 
        self.optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(self.loss,
                                                                method = 'L-BFGS-B',
                                                                options = {'maxiter': 50,
                                                                           'maxfun': 50000,
                                                                           'maxcor': 50,
                                                                           'maxls': 50,
                                                                           'ftol' : 1.0 * np.finfo(float).eps})
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  
        self.sess.run(init)
    def initialize_NN(self, layers):
        weights = []
        biases = []
        num_layers = len(layers)
        for l in range(0,num_layers-1):
            W = self.xavier_init(size=[layers[l], layers[l+1]])
            b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layers[l+1]], dtype=tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32)
            weights.append(W)
            biases.append(b) 
        return weights, biases
    def xavier_init(self, size):
        in_dim = size[0]
        out_dim = size[1]
        xavier_stddev = np.sqrt(2/(in_dim + out_dim)) 
        return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype=tf.float32)
    def neural_net(self, X, weights, biases):
        num_layers = len(weights) + 1
        H = 2.0*(X - self.lb)/(self.ub - self.lb) - 1.0
        for l in range(0,num_layers-2):
            W = weights[l]
            b = biases[l]
            H = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b))
        W = weights[-1]
        b = biases[-1]
        Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b) 
        return Y
    def net(self, x, y, z, t): 
        v1_out = self.neural_net(tf.concat([x,y,z,t], 1), self.weights, self.biases)
        v1 = v1_out[:,0:1]
        return v1
    def callback(self, loss):
        global Nfeval
        print(str(Nfeval)+' - Loss in loop: %.3e' % (loss))
        Nfeval += 1
    def fetch_minibatch(self, x_in, y_in, z_in, t_in, den_in, N_train_sample):  
        idx_batch = np.random.choice(len(x_in), N_train_sample, replace=False)
        x_batch = x_in[idx_batch,:]
        y_batch = y_in[idx_batch,:]
        z_batch = z_in[idx_batch,:]
        t_batch = t_in[idx_batch,:]
        v1_batch = den_in[idx_batch,:] 
        return x_batch, y_batch, z_batch, t_batch, v1_batch
    def train(self, end_it):  
        it = 0
        while it < end_it: 
            x_res_batch, y_res_batch, z_res_batch, t_res_batch, v1_res_batch = self.fetch_minibatch(self.x, self.y, self.z, self.t, self.v1, sample_batch_size) # Fetch residual mini-batch
            tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x_res_batch, self.y_tf: y_res_batch, self.z_tf: z_res_batch, self.t_tf: t_res_batch,
                       self.v1_tf: v1_res_batch}
            self.optimizer.minimize(self.sess,
                                    feed_dict = tf_dict,
                                    fetches = [self.loss],
                                    loss_callback = self.callback) 
    def predict(self, x_star, y_star, z_star, t_star): 
        tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x_star, self.y_tf: y_star, self.z_tf: z_star, self.t_tf: t_star}
        v1_star = self.sess.run(self.v1_pred, tf_dict)  
        return v1_star

model = NeuralNet(x_train, y_train, z_train, t_train, v1_train, layers)

Nfeval = 1
model.train(end_it)
```

Comment: Having a variable that always takes the same value shouldn't be a big issue, I have trained multiple models on datasets like that. Are you normalizing your input? It seems very possible that those come from that, as the mean for `z` would be `1` and the standard deviation would be `0`, so the normalized values would all be `(1 - 1) / 0 = nan`. To avoid that (values with null standard deviation), when I normalize the data I put a safeguard like `x_std = np.std(x, axis=0); x_std[x_std < 1e-6] = 1`.

Comment: @jdehesa The values of `z` were all normalized to be of order unity in a previous preprocessing step, but this problem persists even if `z != 1` (but they are nevertheless all still a single constant, i.e. `z[i] = z[j]`). The standard deviation of the input variable `z` is therefore necessarily 0 since they are all the same. Further clarity and expanding upon what exactly you are suggesting and how it will help would be great.

Comment: The problem I mention happens in any case where the variable always take the same value, doesn't matter which value exactly. In those cases, the result of the normalisation is always 0/0, which is `nan`. You can avoid the issue by replacing standard deviations of 0 (or very close to zero) by some constant, e.g. 1, then the normalisation will be 0/1 which is zero, and the feature will have no effect.

Comment: @jdehesa Yes, but where exactly are you proposing to replace standard deviations? In the updating of weights in the neural network itself? Or elsewhere? A code example implementing your solution (e.g. in TensorFlow) would be helpful.

Comment: It's hard to give an example if you don't give an example yourself. I don't know if you do the normalisation as part of the TensorFlow model itself, or all in NumPy beforehand or what. I compute the stddevs in NumPy but do the normalisation operation within my model (so my inputs are unnormalised), and I replace the null stddevs in advance with NumPy too (with a line like what I wrote above). But I don't know if any of that applies to you. Please try to be concrete about your situation.

Comment: @jdehesa I have now included a minimal working example. If you can indicate (e.g. with an example) how to train against this data and how you've overcome the problem of training against data with a constant input variable in the past, glad to work through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```py
H = 2.0*(X - self.lb)/(self.ub - self.lb) - 1.0
```

In the third column fo `X`, corresponding to the `z` variable, both `self.lb` and `self.ub` are the same value, and equal to the value in the example, in this case `1`, so it is acutally computing:

```py
2.0*(1.0 - 1.0)/(1.0 - 1.0) - 1.0 = 2.0*0.0/0.0 - 1.0
```

Which is `nan`. You can work around the issue in a few different ways, a simple option is to simply do:

```py
# Avoids dividing by zero
X_d = tf.math.maximum(self.ub - self.lb, 1e-6)
H = 2.0*(X - self.lb)/X_d - 1.0
```

Comment: That about solves the problem! I'm just currently testing this solution when training against various data sets, and depending on its robustness, will accept it as the answer. But in the interim, I have awarded it the bounty.

Comment: @Mathews24 Thanks, glad it helps. Let me know if you still find issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting situation. A quick check on an [online tool for regression](http://www.xuru.org/rt/MLR.asp) shows that even simple regression suffers from the problem of unable to fit data points when one of the inputs is constant through the dataset. Taking a look at the [algebraic solution](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/intro.html) for a two-variable linear regression problem shows the solution involving division by standard deviation which, being zero in a constant set, is a problem.

As far as solving through backprop is concerned (as is the case in your neural network), I strongly suspect that the derivative of the loss with respect to the input ([these expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Matrix_multiplication)) is the culprit, and that the algorithm is not able to update the weights `W` using `W := W - α.dZ`, and ends up remaining constant.

Comment: I agree and strongly suspect this derivative with respect to the input is the origin of the problem. I suppose the fundamental question is: what methods can be used to overcome this difficulty during training? If the particular input has no influence on the output, ideally its influence ultimately should be zeroed out in the end. But what is a general way to accomplish this task during training?

Comment: Ideally, you would add data points where `z` is something other than 1, to the training set. If you don't have such data, I wonder if changing one of the existing data points from `z = 1` to `z = 1.000001` would help.

Comment: Correct, adding a bit of variation in `z` on the data points will fix the problem. But the new problem would be I wouldn't want to arbitrarily adjust `z` at the moment on the training data since future training data points will actually have a subtle z-dependence that I don't know a priori. But for now, the simple objective is for the output to not depend on my `z` input without altering the training data itself.